# Durandal - using many widgets causes UI to load "jittery"

Tags: durandal

We have several forms in our application which have made extensive use of widgets.

Unfortunately, this causes the form to load in a very "jittery" manner.   It still loads pretty quickly, but you can perceptively see each widget 'pop' into view one-by-one.

Is this an expected side affect of the widget infrastructure, or is there a technique whereby we can coerce Durandal into constructing the entire view (widgets and all) before attaching, which seems to be how partial views work?  (We were able to convert many of these widgets into partial views to mitigate the phenomenon).

**How to easily reproduce the behavior**

Using the HTML samples, find app/widgets/index.html and make a small modification to create a view which will have lots of widgets:

```
<div>
    <h1>Widgets Sample</h1>
    <!-- ko foreach: new Array(100) -->
    <div data-bind="expander:{items:$root.projects}">
        <h3 data-part="header">Project: <span data-bind="text: name"></span></h3>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <button class="btn" data-bind="click: addNewProject">Add</button>
</div>
```

When refreshing the page, you will see the scrollbar "shrinking down" visibly.  I suspect this is because each individual widget is being added to the DOM one at a time, rather than "all at once with the parent view" which is how partial views work.

Note: The affect is fairly subtle with this very simple markup, but the more complicated the UI elements, the more noticeable and jarring the "studdering" becomes (especially when you have non-widget content nested in between various wisgets).

Comment: Is your app running in production mode (main-build.js)? Otherwise the view/viewmodel html/js for each involved widget has to be loaded on the first use.

Comment: it is running via main-build, yes.  However, it still seems to run each widget through the lifecycle and attach them one-by-one after the parent element has already been attached to the DOM (resulting in the jitter affect).

Comment: Are the widgets doing something async in nature? If so make sure to return a promise from `activate`, so that Durandal knows when it's save to proceed.

Comment: Nope, no async, that is not the issue.   I have updated the question to include how to reproduce.

Comment: I tried to reproduce this: Go to  http://dfiddle.github.io/dFiddle-2.0/#so and then click so21566358 link to load the example. Tested in Chrome and FF without seeing the described behavior. Let me know if I should use another browser/version to reproduce.

Comment: You have reproduced it.  Notice the scrollbar jumps to 3-4 different sizes while the page is loading.  The effect becomes more pronounced as your UI gets more demanding (for example if you are using some jquery or kendoui controls on them).  If you would like to see this clearly, just replace the expander widget markup with 100 select elements with 100 options each.

Comment: Actually after trying in other browsers, it seems that chrome may be the only one which actually paints the browser visbily multiple times.   Other browsers seem to just lag-up a bit and then display everything at once.   I still believe the underlining issue exists though and that we need some way to efficiently render many widgets rather than the existing "attach the parent view, then attach each widget one-by-one".  Btw the 100x100 recommendation is a bit much for non-chrome browsers, 50x50 is probably better :)

Comment: Note: If you follow my recommendation with the select elements, view it in chrome, and hold down the "page down" key, you can really see what's going on if you also add some garbage text after <!-- ko foreach: new Array(100) --> (TEXT HERE)

Comment: I know you said you were using main-built.js but you havent left system.debug(true); enabled?

Comment: unsure, but expectation is that weyland would turn that off with the preprocessor commands:     //>>excludeStart("build", true);
    system.debug(true);
    //>>excludeEnd("build");

Comment: Right, and if it was enabled you would see all the debug info in the console anyway. This is a very strange one, i created a new widget this weekend which has a lot of complexity to it but the performance is excellent.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's no obviouse answer at the moment, but there's an issue at https://github.com/BlueSpire/Durandal/issues/434 that is cross linked with this questions.

Comment: Yes, I added that today since it is looking like it is just an inherent performance penalty associated with widgets as-implemented.  Thanks for your help.